# Simular click em um template compilado

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Estou enfrentando problemas ao atribuir um evento 'click' em um template externo previamente compilado, segue o código...

Diretiva

```
angular.module('testeFuncoes').directive('fechaMenu', function($templateRequest, $compile) {

    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attr) { 

               $templateRequest("template.html").then(function(html){

                    var template = angular.element(html);
                    element.html($compile(template)(scope));
                    var cnt = $(element).contents();
                    $(element).replaceWith(cnt);

                    $('.ctnTeste').trigger('click');

               });  


        },

    }
})
```

Template

```
    <md-menu-bar>
      <md-menu>

        <div class="ctnTeste" ng-click="openMenu($mdMenu, ev)" style="display: flex; padding: 20px; background-color: black">
                <div class="subTeste" style="padding:{{color.red}}px; background-color:rgb(1,10,{{color.red}});"></div>
                <div class="subTeste" id="teste"></div>
        </div>...
```

Ou seja ao injetar esse template quero simular um click nele, porém dentro da função link. Ao passar pelo trigger, ele me da o seguinte erro [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress, porém se eu atribuir o evento manualmente funciona, exemplo...

```
  $('.testebotao').on('click', function() {
    $('.ctnTeste').trigger('click');
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este erro indica que o ciclo do `$digest` do Angular já está rodando enquanto você tenta rodá-lo de novo. Alguns métodos do jQuery podem causar este erro.

A solução é utilizar um `$timeout`. Por exemplo:

```
$timeout(function(){
  //Código a ser executado separado do $digest
});
```

Como não sei identificar qual parte específica do seu código está disparando esse erro, recomendo colocar o máximo que puder dentro desse `$timeout` (sem sair do método original, claro).